# Emission on part of the mesh

Tags: unity, blender, materials

I would like to port this mesh in Unity but in a way that smaller face, which is selected, has emission material and rest of the mesh has albedo material.

I know how to apply material in Blender on different faces but I don't know how to port it in Unity this way.

[image]

Updated post: emission texture

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set the UVs for your model, make sure the faces which are supposed to have a different material get assigned to different images. When you then import the model into Unity, you will have a different material-slot for each image in your model. You can then drag-and-drop different materials into those.

Another option is to use one material for everything and add an [emission texture](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialParameterEmission.html) to it. Make that texture black except for those parts of the texture which are supposed to glow. In that case you don't need any specific geometry in your mesh just to define the emissive parts. You can do that with the texture. Here is an example for such an emission texture from the Unity documentation:

[image]

Comment: I don't know how to UVs the model but I understand your second option. Only for the emission texture, how to position the emission part of the texture on the prefab in Unity ? I want to be on lower part of the prefab. I updated the post with emission texture.

Comment: @Wildfire You might want to learn how to set UV coordinates in Blender then. It tells the renderer how to put the textures on your model. There are lots of tutorials available for that. Editing the UV coordinates in Unity is not possible (well, you could try to build a custom editor, but that wouldn't really be feasible)